# How to get value of dynamic add inputs

Tags: javascript, json, forms, input

I have some problems with Js. I need to add a form in HTML Document when the user clicks on the button. I write this code:

```
plusBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const newLine = document.createElement('div');
    newLine.classList.add('line');
    newLine.innerHTML = `
        <textarea form="shopForm" class="form-control form-data" name="comment" id="comment" rows="3" placeholder="Комментарий" required></textarea>
        <input form="shopForm" type="text" class="form-control form-data" name="price" id="price" placeholder="Цена" required>
        <input form="shopForm" class="form-data" type="number" name="amount" id="amount" required>`;
    dataForm.append(newLine);
});
```

And I need to create a formData in my custom format with several items. In my HTML document, I have `<form>` and js add my inputs in the form. And because I use `.querySelectorAll` I can't get access to these inputs, because they are dynamic nodes.

```
dataForm.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(window);
    const formData = new FormData(dataForm),
            comment = document.querySelectorAll('.form-comment'),
            price = document.querySelectorAll('.form-price'),
            amount = document.querySelectorAll('.form-amount');

    console.log(comment);

    formData.append('product_url', productUrl.value);
    formData.append('user_id', userId);
    formData.append('delivery_type_id', delivery.value);
    formData.append('package_type_id', package.value);
    if (comment.length > 1) {
        let items = [];
        comment.forEach((item, i) => {
            let obj = {};
            obj.comment = item.value;
            obj.price = price[i].value;
            obj.amount = amount[i].value;
            items.push(obj);
        });
        formData.append('items', JSON.stringify(items));
    } else {
        let items = [];
        items.push({
            'comment': comment[0].value,
            'price': price[0].value,
            'amount': amount[0].value
        });
        formData.append('items', JSON.stringify(items));
    }

    dataAjaxSend(formData)
        .then((response) => {
            console.log(JSON.parse(response));
        })
        .catch((err) => console.log('Eror' + err))
});
```

I don't know how to create inputs and get access to them. Thanks for you help)

Answer (score 0):

Just because you created the dom nodes using js does not mean you can not access them. they are there and you can get them. Your issue is that you are using`document.querySelectorAll('.form-comment')` and not adding that class to it when you are creating it.

```
plusBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const newLine = document.createElement('div');
    newLine.classList.add('line');
    newLine.innerHTML = `
        <textarea form="shopForm" class="form-control form-data form-comment" name="comment" id="comment" rows="3" placeholder="Комментарий" required></textarea>
        <input form="shopForm" type="text" class="form-control form-data form-price" name="price" id="price" placeholder="Цена" required>
        <input form="shopForm" class="form-data form-amount" type="number" name="amount" id="amount" required>`;
    dataForm.append(newLine);
});
```

Also try to steer clear from using the same ID on elements, IDS are meant to be unique. since you are not using labels for these elements ids are not required.

Answer (score 0):

You made a small mistake of not adding the class which you later used to search in `.querySelectorAll`

```
newLine.innerHTML = `
    <textarea form="shopForm" class="form-comment form-control form-data" name="comment" id="comment" rows="3" placeholder="Комментарий" required></textarea>
    <input form="shopForm" type="text" class="form-price form-control form-data" name="price" id="price" placeholder="Цена" required>
    <input form="shopForm" class="form-amount form-data" type="number" name="amount" id="amount" required>`;
```

See & run below code snippet for better understanding.

```js
const plusBtn = document.getElementById('plus')

const dataForm = document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0]

plusBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const newLine = document.createElement('div');
    newLine.classList.add('line');
    newLine.innerHTML = `
        <textarea form="shopForm" class="form-comment form-control form-data" name="comment" id="comment" rows="3" placeholder="Комментарий" required></textarea>
        <input form="shopForm" type="text" class="form-price form-control form-data" name="price" id="price" placeholder="Цена" required>
        <input form="shopForm" class="form-amount form-data" type="number" name="amount" id="amount" required>`;
    dataForm.append(newLine);
});

const submitFunc = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    const formData = new FormData(dataForm),
            comment = document.querySelectorAll('.form-comment')[0],
            price = document.querySelectorAll('.form-price')[0],
            amount = document.querySelectorAll('.form-amount')[0];

    console.log(comment);

    formData.append('product_url', productUrl.value);
    formData.append('user_id', userId);
    formData.append('delivery_type_id', delivery.value);
    formData.append('package_type_id', package.value);
    if (comment.length > 1) {
        let items = [];
        comment.forEach((item, i) => {
            let obj = {};
            obj.comment = item.value;
            obj.price = price[i].value;
            obj.amount = amount[i].value;
            items.push(obj);
        });
        formData.append('items', JSON.stringify(items));
    } else {
        let items = [];
        items.push({
            'comment': comment[0].value,
            'price': price[0].value,
            'amount': amount[0].value
        });
        formData.append('items', JSON.stringify(items));
    }

    dataAjaxSend(formData)
        .then((response) => {
            console.log(JSON.parse(response));
        })
        .catch((err) => console.log('Eror' + err))
    return false
}

dataForm.addEventListener('submit', submitFunc)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>repl.it</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <button id="plus">Plus</button>
    <form>
      <input name="dummy" value="dummy" />
      <input type="submit" />
    </form>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```